# Reading text files with specific format in C

Tags: c, parsing, text-files

I've been trying to read a text file containing a database of books in C which has a specific format.
Here is what I have so far:

```
#include "database_main.h"

struct Book getDetailsFromFile(FILE *ptr)
{
    struct Book bookVar;    /*new book variable as struct*/
    char title[MAX_TITLE_LENGTH+1], author[MAX_AUTHOR_LENGTH+1];   /*temp variables to input data*/
    int year;

    fscanf(ptr, "Title: %100[0-9a-zA-Z ]\n", title);    /*fscanf collecting up to 100 character of only numbers or letters*/
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", title);

    fscanf(ptr, "Author: %100[0-9a-zA-Z ]\n", author);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", author);

    fscanf(ptr, "Year: %i\n\n", &year);
    fprintf(stderr, "%i\n", year);

    strcpy(bookVar.title, title);   /*transfering values to stuct*/
    strcpy(bookVar.author, author);
    bookVar.year = year;
    bookVar.right = NULL;
    bookVar.left = NULL;
    return bookVar;
}

/* read file containing database of books */
void read_book_database ( char *file_name )
{
    FILE *fptr;   /*file pointer*/
    if ((fptr = fopen(file_name, "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! opening file\n");   /*catch error*/
    }
    else
    {
        while (feof(fptr) == 0) /*do until end of file*/
        {
            addBook(getDetailsFromFile(fptr));   /*adds book to database from the file*/
            fprintf(stderr, "Got Book\n");
        } 
        fprintf(stderr, "closing file\n");
        fclose(fptr);
    }
}
```

When the code is run it continuously repeats *"Got Book"* without ever printing any details of the book.

I've also tried using `fgets()` which does input the data however seems to separate out the year field to an entirely new book in the database with no other information. This is not an issue with `addBook()` as this has been tested with manual inputs and works correctly.

Secondly `fgets()` doesn't cut out the Title: and such fields at the beginning of each line of the file.
I have tried some of the other online solutions however none have worked.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Also please note this is being compiled with the ANSI standard.

Comment: What does stepping through the code for `GetDetailListFromFile` tell you?

Comment: You have `while (feof(fptr) == 0)`. Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) Then the function that reads the data, ignores the return value from `fscanf` so the final data will give a bogus result.

Comment: I would make the following changes to make things a bit more clear and easier to debug:
- create a user defined type for your book structure, so you can create variables and clear out all of the "structure" uses.
- create a local variable in `read_book_database()` so you can inspect what gets returned from `getDetailsFromFile()`.  That way you will be able to narrow the search for the problem.

Comment: @Roberto Caboni `struct Book getDetailsFromFile()` returns a coy of `struct Book bookVar;`  Not certain how `addBook()` uses that.

Comment: Bobo, post something we can compile - a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

So the while(feof(fptr)==0) turned out to be the issue and I've now upadted the whole thing to the following:

```
void read_book_database ( char *file_name )
{
    char c[1000];
    FILE *fptr;
    if ((fptr = fopen(file_name, "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! opening file\n");
    }
    else
    {
        struct Book newBook;
        for(newBook;fscanf(fptr, "Title: %100[0-9a-zA-Z ,]\nAuthor: %100[0-9a-zA-Z ,]\nYear: %i\n\n", &(newBook.title), &(newBook.author), &(newBook.year))==3;)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Title: %s\nAuthor: %s\nYear: %i\n\n", newBook.title, newBook.author, newBook.year);
            addBook(newBook);
            /*addBook(getDetailsFromFile(fptr));*/
            fprintf(stderr, "Got Book\n");
        } 
        fprintf(stderr, "closing file\n");
        fclose(fptr);
    }
}
```

It does now cause some issues in different points of the program but I don't think that's related to the reading of the text file so I believe this particular issue is fixed. Thanks everyone for the help